# Swift4 CoreData -- NSManagedObjectModel catch a fatal error

Tags: core-data, swift4

I am now studying coreData in Swift. I made a simple test model to test CoreData, but failed. (xcode 9.3, Entites were created with Codegen "Class Definition").

Established coreDataStack in a independent swift file and built project, it caught a fatal error. "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", and I do not know how to deal with this. Please feel free to contact me if you need other detail. Your help would be highly appreciate.

```
class coreDataStack {
var context: NSManagedObjectContext
var psc: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
var model: NSManagedObjectModel
init () {
    let applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count - 1] as NSURL
    }()

    self.model = {
        let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Model", withExtension: "momd")
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL!)!
    }() //<<<----Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    ......
```

Comment: Why do you use this antique `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` way? State-of-the-art is `NSPersistentContainer` where the URLs are inferred. Most likely the error occurs because the model file could not be found. By the way: Class names are supposed to start with a capital letter and don't use `NSURL` in Swift 3+

Comment: Thanks very much for your points and kindly help. I would check them further by following your comments.